# Chrome Extension to annotate Stack Exchange images

Tags: chrome, stack-exchange, annotation

I'm looking for an extension that allows me to annotate the images that are uploaded to imgur by Stack Exchange.

This would mean drawing circles / 'drawing' text etc..

Comment: Sadly the [Stack Exchange SuperCollider Freehand Circle Editor](http://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange™-supercollider-freehand-circle™-editor-now-supported-on-every-s) is no longer available :(

Comment: @GeorgeGarside That's unfortunate :( It looked perfect - . -

Comment: @grgarside you might be interested in my [answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/20479/2675) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@grgarside](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7025/chrome-extension-to-annotate-stack-exchange-images#comment11371_7025) mentions, there *used* to be a [userscript to do this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange%E2%84%A2-supercollider-freehand-circle%E2%84%A2-editor-now-supported-on-every-s), but it no longer works, and the owner has stopped updating it as he no longer has time to maintain it :(

So, I made my own userscript Freehand Circles Drawing Tool. I've made a [post at StackApps](https://stackapps.com/q/6353/26088).

It allows you to view any image on any SE site, and start drawing on top of it. A button is added to each image called `edit`. Clicking it converts the image to a canvas where you can draw whatever you want on top of the image. Clicking `save` then makes a new image with the annotation and uploads it to imgur. It then updates the post with the new image.

You can therefore easily make images like:

[image]

(original image from [here](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos); everything red is by me :)

### To find out more about how to install and use, go to [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/q/6353/26088) :)